# Laravel Nova 404 at source map files

Tags: laravel, laravel-nova

In my Chrome DevTools I see this Erros:

```
DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for http://xxx.yyy.net.local/nova-api/styles/filter.css.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE_FAILURE
DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for http://xxx.yyy.net.local/nova-api/scripts/filter.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE_FAILURE
```

How can I find out why this errors appear?

I use v3.32.0 version of Laravel Nova.

Answer (score 0):

Both map files exist? if yes check in the end of both files, maybe you need to change the reference path.

Comment: I don't have any of this files. I wonder why or where they requested.

Comment: Do you have filter.css and filter.js (without .map). right? loog at the end of both.
If they not exists...... you need to looking about wich other file is calling these .map files.